# Woocommerce - override the default product page URL structure for a simpler one

Tags: wordpress, mod-rewrite, woocommerce

Woocommerce makes product pages have a

www.example.com/product/product-category/.../product-title

URL structure.

I'd prefer a much simpler

www.example.com/product-title

On normal Wordpress sites I'd have used mod-rewrite to achieve this, but here I am a bit lost.

What would you suggest?

Comment: You aren't required to use the product category in the permalink. However, for custom post types you do need to have the post type as a base. You can use `www.example.com/product/product-title` or `www.example.com/shop/product-title`. Without a base WooCommerce will use `www.example.com/?product=product-title`.

Comment: You can do this easily using redirect(s) in your htaccess.

Comment: Thanks. With a combination of removing the custom post type and mod-rewrite I have managed to do what I wanted.